# OpenCV Faster way to do the matching when comparing to the same Descriptors?

Tags: python, opencv

so currently I have one big Image with a lot of Features/Descriptors and a few smaller Images I am iterating through. I detect Features + Descriptors on the smaller Images and  and than I try to get the matches to the big Image.
Is there a way to make the whole matching faster, like some kind of indexing, since the descriptors I am matching to ( of the big Image) stay always the same?

At the moment I am using BFMatcher, I know that the FlannBasedMatcher is faster but it does not always return the best match, which is important in my case.

Comment: It might help if you provide samples of your images or provide a description of what type of images you have.

Comment: @fmw42 all grayscale. The big Image is taken by a sattelite, the smaller ones by a drone.

Comment: If you are computing the large image features for every small image, can you not just move that outside the loop and use the same large image descriptors without having to recompute them for every match?

Comment: @fmw42 I am computing the features and descriptors only once for the big image. But the bottleneck is doing the matching between the small images and the big one.

Comment: I do not see any further savings possible since you do not know which large features match the small ones.

Comment: Interesting I thought, I could maybe store the Descriptors of the big Image in some kind of index and than it would be faster two find the closest match.

Comment: Do you work with binary descriptors? I believe they should be much faster because of the more simple matching strategy using the Hamming distance.